# Inline gradient background

Tags: html-email

Is there a way to display a gradient background in a table cell using inline code without using an image?

I am using in house software developed by a client and it cannot handle inline images, so I am hoping to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that is 100% compatible.

You could use CSS3 techniques that would probably work in webkit based clients like Mac, and maybe combine it with VML, which might give you a solution for Outlook.